# Confusion regarding simulation in Simulink?

Tags: simulation, matlab, simulink

Please check the attached snap especially the portion in red marked area, which is simulation stop time and it has default value of 10? Is it 10 second or any other unit? According to my experience, if block diagram is small this '10' units time passes very quickly, but if block diagram is relatively complex, it take relatively big amount of time.

I have also added another snap, that is of a complex block  diagram and shows two red marks on that snap, one is 10 units at top and other is loading percentage at bottom. I compared the time with my stop watch but it took approximately 35 seconds on my stopwatch for the time Simulink loading percentage gone through 0 to 100%.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "10 second" is simulation time which has nothing to do with real world timing. It signifies how your model will behav for the first 10 seconds.

The time it takes for MATLAB on your computer to execute all the parameters in your simulation purely depending on

1. Solver you are using.
2. Processing speed of your computer. eg. if you are using a super computer to run your simulation, it will complete the sim in a fraction of a second and show you the behaviour of your model for 10 long seconds.